# Two filters with an OR-condition on RethinkDB

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I've a struct :

```
type Talk struct {
    Id string `gorethink:"id,omitempty"`
    MatchId string
    UserIdX string
    UserIdY string
    UserNameX string
    UserNameY string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

My current `Talk` struct looks like this:

```
{
    "CreatedAt": Wed Sep 14 2016 21:36:26 GMT+02:00 ,
    "MatchId":  "172d51fa-438b-49a5-bbe5-422377f09336" ,
    "UserIdX":  "acc4e0b6-d33b-4755-9c0a-ae5309c2ba75" ,
    "UserIdY":  "03f76d8b-ed6a-4c0f-9cde-27b17c9e7cdb" ,
    "UserNameX":  "Barbara" ,
    "UserNameY":  "Louis" ,
    "id":  "ead3f1b0-b242-4c6d-8027-a59572b58649"
}
```

How can I retrieve a talk, with a single query, where:

> (UserIdX == talk.UserIdX AND UserIdY == talk.UserIdY) OR (UserIdX ==
>   talk.UserIdY AND UserIdY == talk.UserIdX)

I actually do it like the following:

```
func (talk *Talk) GetTalkByUsersId() bool {
    talk1 := new(Talk)
    talk2 := new(Talk)

    curs, _ :=  r.Table("Talks").
                Filter(r.Row.Field("UserIdX").Eq(talk.UserIdX)).
                Filter(r.Row.Field("UserIdY").Eq(talk.UserIdY)).
                Run(api.Sess)

    curs2, _ :=  r.Table("Talks").
                Filter(r.Row.Field("UserIdX").Eq(talk.UserIdY)).
                Filter(r.Row.Field("UserIdY").Eq(talk.UserIdX)).
                Run(api.Sess)

    curs.One(&talk1)
    curs2.One(&talk2)
    if talk1.Id == "" && talk2.Id == "" {
        return false
    }
    if talk1.Id != "" {
        talk.copyTalk(talk1)
    } else {
        talk.copyTalk(talk2)
    }
    return true
}
```

How can I get this to work in a much simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to summon @daniel-cannon here but I think this is what you're looking for and will vastly simplify this query and reduce it to just a single query. But just two tips:

- `r.And` and `r.Or` and their two use cases are very much your friends for doing some tricky logical conditions.

  - https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#and
  - https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#or
- You can provide anonymous functions to `.Filter` to do things that would be kind of ugly with the simplified `r.Row` pattern.

```golang
r.Table("talks").Filter(func(talk r.Term) r.Term {
    return r.Or(
        r.And(talk.Field("UserIdX").Eq(UserIdX), talk.Field("UserIdX").Eq(UserIdY)),
        r.And(talk.Field("UserIdY").Eq(UserIdX), talk.Field("UserIdX").Eq(UserIdY)),
    )
}).Run(api.Sess)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @dalanmiller! That looks like it should work, there were a couple of very small Go syntax errors (I have submitted an edit which addresses these) but I think it should answer @Fantasim's question.

Comment: I had previously seen or and and function , but I did not realize it worked like that, thanks a lot!